# What is a good example for task parallelismn in data processing?

Tags: database, parallel-processing, data-processing

In order to process data in a distributed setting, you can do task parallelization or data parallelization. So far I only came across data parallelization.

**Task parallelism:** break task into smaller tasks and process them in parrallel.

**Data parallelism:** break data into smaller chunks of data and process them in parralel.

For example MapReduce to me is data parallelization, because you would partition the data to the different mappers. Also algorithmns like bucket sort are data parallelization, because you break up the data to be sortet in “buckets” and give those to the different nodes.

In practive there seems to be no “pure” task parallelization without data paralellization. For example, if we would want to process a big CSV-file and process each column differently by an independend node, to me it would also make sens to break up the data by column (so also data parallelization).

**Is there an example for task parallelization without data parallelization?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of my PhD work I have a large data analysis project. It has many different steps that we have to do. Some steps depend on each other, some others are independent. The following is a generated diagram with the dependency flow. Blue nodes are data, white nodes are scripts/tasks and yellow nodes are generated reports. You see how some tasks depend on some data and generate other data:

[image]

In order to run those we can employ task parallellism. Once we have `corr_matrix.Rdata` available, we can run the `outlier.R` script. Once that is through we can generate the `10_outlier.Rmd` report as well as running the `outlier_removal.R` script. This is just a little fraction of all the tasks that we perform, and usually one can run a handful of things in parallel.

In order to make use of task parallelization you need to have a bunch of different tasks. When you only have a single task, all you can do is parallelize over the data.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can the 3 tasks coming out of outlier.R be performed in parralel? Do they each need the entire data or do you also split up the data.

Comment: There are not three tasks coming out of `outlier.R`, but three data sets (blue). These data sets are then used for other tasks. They just need the data that is indicated with the arrows, so `10_outlier.Rmd` needs three data sets and `outlier_removal.R` needs two different data sets. If you have generated the data needed for a task, it can be run. I am not sure what you mean with “entire data”. Each task needs to have each dependency in full, but say for `outlier_removal.R` I only need `corr_matrix` and `outlier_keep` but not `bootstrap_parameters`.